# List certain user ids and drop them in Oracle

Tags: oracle, users

How do I list certain user ids and drop them?

For instance, I want to list user ids directly connected to database, in Oracle, and not any functional id.

I need to write a script for the automation

I want to write a script to list such direct ids and drop them automaticaly.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

To select a list if users connected to the database:

```
select distinct USERNAME
from v$session;
```

Note that some will be internal Oracle sessions.

To drop a user in Oracle, you use the `DROP USER` command:

```
DROP USER USERNAME;
```

Scripting it is easy, you can run in a loop and use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, or spool a query from SQL*Plus to create the script for you:

```
  select 'drop user '||USERNAME||';' 
  from v$session
  where username not in (... LIST OF USERS YOU DONT WANT TO DROP ...);
```

I do wonder why on earth you'd want to automate this though. Seems like a very bizarre business case.